# Django ImportError: No module named django

Tags: django, terminal, python-2.7, virtualenv, pip

So, I have python 2.7.3 installed and I used the Django website https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/ to install Django on my Mac OS x Mountain Lion. I used pip and virtual env, I currently am able to use Django from my current terminal but, when I open a new terminal and try say:

```
$ cd Django 
$ cd djangowork
$ cd firstproj
$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

This is the error I get.
I have looked online for a solution to my problem. It seems to be a common problem, dealing with the PATH. But, I cannot figure out how to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

This is an example of what my working terminal looks like: (but if I exit out I lose everything)

```
(my_new_env)$ cd Django
(my_new_env)$ cd djangowork
(my_new_env)$ cd firstproj
(my_new_env)$ ls
firstproj   manage.py   testdb
(my_new_env)$ python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
October 31, 2012 - 18:51:22
Django version 1.6.dev20121029143154, using settings 'firstproj.settings'
Development server is running at http://.../
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how in the second case you have `(my_new_env)` before the prompt, but not in the first?  That's because only in the second case have you run virtual env properly.  Make sure you run `source my_new_env/bin/activate` before you run any python commands at the prompt.  You should always have `(my_new_env)` before the prompt in order to make sure your environment is set up properly.  **You have to do this in every terminal window that you open.**

Comment: $ source venv/bin/activate
-bash: venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory

Comment: source my_new_env/bin/activate
i had to use this instead! thank you so much!! :D

Comment: Ah, I see.  You put it in a non-standard location.  The norm is to put it in `venv`, not `my_new_env`.  I will edit my answer to show this to help others.

Comment: To help manage virtual envrionments, consider installing [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It is a set of scripts that help manage your virtual environments.